# why executing a controller that triggers a job outputs integers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm new to Rails.

I have a simple controller with a method that triggers a job.  I have sidekiq running. When I try to execute it from the console, the output is a series of integers. What does it mean?

controller:

```
class DownloadersController

 def email
  Jobs.enqueue(:send_download_drive_link, to_address: 'example@email.com', drive_url: 'www.google.com')
 end

end
```

In my console, I run the following:

```
[6] pry(main)> x = DownloadersController.new
=> #<DownloadersController:0x007fd2f31a8a88
 @_action_has_layout=true,
 @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"},
 @_request=nil,
 @_response=nil,
 @_routes=nil,
 @_status=200>
[7] pry(main)> x.email
=> "a8d82b6be3f8fd74fb230ab9"
```

What is this hash-looking output? Shouldn't the job be triggered?

Comment: it's the ID of the Job

Comment: Not sure where `Jobs.enqueue` is coming from but sidekiq jobs are usually triggered using `MyJob.perform_now` or `MyJob.perform_later`

Comment: @CarlMarkham: that's ActiveJob api. And enqueue is probably the [resque compat layer](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Resque-Compatibility) (although, on a second thought, it seems to be something else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby implicitly returns the value of the last expression. In your case it seems to be the id of the queued job.

Comment: That means your job is enqueued, if you have sidekiq running it should process and run it. It seems you want to send an email, if so you should read about the integration between action mailer and active job http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#action-mailer